# cannot sort a vector of objects that has array in it

Tags: class, vector

Hi I am using a class that has an integer and array and creating a vector of the classes objects but I cannot sort it  also don't know to store in it.

I am a BEGINNER on c++ so i just wanted to know if I am wrong and how to
do that thing

here n = no of times the program has to execute

num = to store the no. of elements in vector a

```
 but problem loop for(j=0;j<arr[i].a.end();j++)
 and also pushback is not working

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class subcont
{
public:
    int num;
    vector<int> a;

};

 int main() 
{
    vector<subcont> arr(100); 
   int i,j,k,l,n,num1,num2;


cin>>n;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   cin>>arr[i].num;        

    for(j=0;j<arr[i].num;j++)
        {
            cin>>num2;
            cin>>arr[i].a.pushback(num2);

        }

}


for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

  sort(arr[i].a.begin(),arr[i].a.end()); 

}

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        cout<<arr[i].num; 

        for(j=0;j<arr[i].a.end();j++)
            cout<<arr[i].a[j];  
    }




return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you describe sound as if you could at least *compile* your code, which I can't. In fact, the compiler error messages (if one first ignores the large amount of error noise generated by unhappy templates) should hint to most important problems.

Logical problems on first sight: In `for(j=0;j<k;j++)` the value of `k` is undefined. In `for(j=0;j<arr[i].a.end();a++)` the `a++` does not make sense.
In `cin>>arr[i].a.pushback[num];` the `num` should probably be `num2`. Please check your code for more such typoes.

Your sort fails because `a` is a C array and not a C++ container, so `a.begin()` and `a.end()` are not defined.

Stylistic problem: While it makes life a lot easier, mayn people strictly recommend to *not* use `using namespace std;`

Additional remark: Why not use `std::vector<int>` in place of `subcont`?

Comment: Thanks, for helping me out

Comment: the sort function is resolved but Mr.Hagen  the loop and the pushback are not working even i corrected the as you told me